# How to export SSRS reports to Excel without Errors and Warnings?

Tags: excel, visualization, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

[image]I built a SSRS report but exporting it to Excel gives me errors and warnings before showing the data. My SSRS report contains some images, text boxes and embedded images behind but I only want numerical data (table) from the report in Excel.

Thanks.

I tried creating the button, clicking on which table should download (but it gives the same error)

Comment: What errors/warning do you get?

Comment: It says "we found some errors in <report name> .. (image attached)

Comment: After this message you should get another message/dialog box that allows you to see the details. This should provide more info. This typically happens when your data has too many decimal places or is too large for excel to handle. Also, you can prevent report objects (charts etc) from being exported by setting the `hidden` property to only hide when the `renderformat` is `EXCELXML`

Comment: Thanks Alan. Yes, I do get a message. But, my whole concern is to remove the error while I export.

Comment: I know so if we know what the detailed error is, we might be able to help. If could be a number of things...